# FutureBuilder doesn't wait until future completes

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

In my app I want to initialize something before my widgets will be created. I need to do it exactly in `App` class and trying to use FutureBuilder for this purpose. But `_AppBlocProvider`'s `build` method is called before `initInjectionContainer()`, for example. My repository is not initialised yet in injectionContainer, but Blocs in provider are trying to access it's instance. What's wrong with this code?

[image]

I've also tried this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  Future<bool>? _myFuture;

  Future<bool> _init() async {
    ...
    await initInjectionContainer();
    await sl<AudioManager>().preloadFiles();
    return false;
  }

  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myFuture = _init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _myFuture,
      builder: (context, _) {
        return _BlocProvider(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              ),
              home: MainMenu(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` doesn't just automatically block or show a loading screen or whatever. It builds once on initialization, and then again once the future completes. That second parameter in the builder that you anonymized is crucial to properly handling the state of the future and building accordingly.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: _someFuture(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
      // Future not done, return a temporary loading widget
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    // Future is done, handle it properly
    return ...
  },
),
```

That being said, if there is stuff that your entire app needs that you need to initialize, you can call it from `main` before you call `runApp` so that they become a part of the runtime loading process rather than forcing a widget to deal with it:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initInjectionContainer();
  await sl<AudioManager>().preloadFiles();

  runApp(App());
}
```

Now with *that* being said, if these processes can take a while, it's better to handle them with a widget so that you can display a loading state to the user so they know the app didn't just freeze on start-up.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But in my case I want to be able to import my github repository and use my App with ALL it's resources, like images etc... so I can't call main() method while importing this Widget in another package.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, my fault for poor understanding of FutureBuilder.

Comment: @YaroBest Why don't you add all those resources to your app as assets? Why are you downloading them from Github?

Comment: It's a game, and I want to be able to use it in whatever app I want, just importing it and passing in implementation of it's statistics repository. So all my resources are in lib/assets.